# cancelling a search using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to multi-threading. I am using c++ on unix.

In the code below, runSearch() takes a long time and I want to be able to kill the search as soon as "cancel == true". The function cancelSearch is called by another thread.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks you..

------------------This is the existing code-------------------------

```
    struct SearchTask : public Runnable
    {
        bool cancel = false;

        void cancelSearch()
        {
           cancel = true;
        }

        void run()
        {
            cancel = false;
            runSearch();
            if (cancel == true)
            {
                return;
            }
            //...more steps.
        }
    }
```

EDIT: To make it more clear, say runSearch() takes 10 mins to run. After 1 min, cancel==true, then I want to exit out of run() immediately rather than waiting another 9 more mins for runSearch() to complete.

Comment: Please give the code for `runSearch()`

Comment: Just as a tip, you're probably going to want to declare `cancel` as being `volatile`.

Comment: @user1566608 You may need to call `runSearch()` from a separate process and kill that from `cancelSearch()`

Comment: Yeah, cancel should be declared volatile.. Thanks 

@peacemaker, the code for runSearch() is not visible to me..

Comment: The `volatile` keyword does nothing thread-related. It's just a decoration to the type, like `const`, but far less functional.

Comment: @quamrana That seems a workable solution. Thank you!

Comment: Is runSearch() totally opaque, code and data?  Is there some data it operates on that you can err.. 'get at' while it's running?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to keep checking the flag throughout the search operation.  Something like this:

```
    void run()
    {
        cancel = false;            
        while (!cancel)
        {
            runSearch();
            //do your thread stuff...
        }
    }
```

Comment: It still does not solve my problem. I want to kill runSearch() when I find cancel == true.

Comment: then you need to have the check inside `runSearch()`.  Or split `runSearch()` into batches.  The function will run to the end unless you check something incrementally, like your cancel flag

Comment: I cannot split runSearch() as this is implemented by another subsystem.

Comment: Once you trigger `runSearch()` if there is no way of messaging that function (via callback etc.) then you simply can't interrupt it in the way you want.

Comment: But I could still kill the search if it is running on a different thread, instead of interrupting it.

Comment: Ok, well that is platform specific.  You can terminate a thread using the handle and appropriate function.  Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx  
*nix: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cancel.html

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you cannot modify runSearch(). With pthreads there's a `pthread_setcancelstate()` function, however I don't believe this is safe, especially with C++ code that expects RAII semantics.

Safe thread cancellation *must be cooperative*. The code that gets canceled must be aware of the cancellation and be able to clean up after itself. If the code is not designed to do this and is simply terminated then your program will probably exhibit undefined behavior.

For this reason C++'s std::thread does not offer any method of thread cancellation and instead the code must be written with explicit cancellation checks as other answers have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic method that accepts a action / delegate. Have each step be something REALLY small and specific. Send the generic method a delegate / action of what you consider a "step". In the generic method detect if cancel is true and return if true. Because steps are small if it is cancelled it shouldn't take long for the thread to die.

That is the best advice I can give without any code of what the steps do.

Also note :

```
 void run()
{
    cancel = false;
    runSearch();
    while (!cancel)
    {
        //do your thread stuff...
    }
}
```

Won't work because if what you are doing is not a iteration it will run the entire thread before checking for !cancel. Like I said if you can add more details on what the steps do it would easier to give you advice. When working with threads that you want to halt or kill, your best bet is to split your code into very small steps.

Comment: I cannot split runSearch() as this is implemented by another subsystem.

Comment: Well you can still implement my way for the extra steps after search. And at least then once it has been cancelled the thread will just die. If you do not have control over this runSearch() method, or the runSearch() does not have arguments to accept cancellation you are out of luck. Because you just put "runSearch" it was assumed by everyone it was in the same class.

Comment: I could atleast kill the search if it is running on a different thread, can't I?

In that case, I wouldn't need to send interrupt to this function.

Comment: Terminating threads is usually OS specific if you don't do it your self like having a cancel variable. If you can not modify the runSearch() I don't think there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to poll the `cancel` flag everywhere. There are other tricks you could use, but they are more platform-specific, like thread cancellation, or are not general enough like interrupts.

And `cancel` needs to be an atomic variable (like in std::atomic, or just protected it with a mutex) otherwise the compiler might just cache the value in a register and not see the update coming from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the responses is right - just because you've called a blocking function in a thread doesn't mean it magically turns into a non-blocking call. The thread may not interrupt the rest of the program, but it still has to wait for the runSearch call to complete.

OK, so there are ways round this, but they're not necessarily safe to use.

You can kill a thread explicitly. On Windows you can use [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() that will kill the thread execution. Sound good right? Well, except that it is very dangerous to use - unless you know exactly what all the resources and calls are going on in the killed thread, you may find yourself with an app that refuses to work correctly next time round. If runSearch opens a DB connection for example, the TerminateThread call will not close it. Same applies to memory, loaded dlls, and all they use. Its designed for killing totally unresponsive threads so you can close a program and restart it.

Given the above, and the very strong recommendation you not use it, the next step is to call the runSearch in a external manner - if you run your blocking call in a separate process, then the process can be killed with a lot more certainty that you won't bugger everything else up. The process dies, clears up its memory, its heap, any loaded dlls, everything. So inside your thread, call CreateProcess and wait on the handle. You'll need some form on IPC (probably best not to use shared memory as it can be a nuisance to reset that when you kill the process) to transfer the results back to your main app. If you need to kill this process, call [ExitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it's handle (or [exit](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_exit.htm) in Linux)
Note that these exit calls require to be called inside the process, so you'll need to run a thread inside the process for your blocking call. You can terminate a process externally, but again, its dangerous - not nearly as dangerous as killing a thread, but you can still trip up occasionally. (use [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) for this)